# How to add a spring boot security layer with OAuth2 for form based login authentication?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I'm completely beginner for writing security code with spring boot and OAuth2.

I need of some sample REST API that have the login functionality with OAuth2 authorization server and resource server.

Could anyone please help me to understand? Thought's would be grateful and appreciated.

Comment: here there are 5 articles teaching how to build an oauth resource and authetication server, you can also download the project from github. https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v

Comment: @Rafael ZeffaThanks for your response. I seen this link https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v. I could understand about the Auth server implementation. But, what i'm looking to achieve is i have a separate app developed using spring boot that will act as a REST API and i have another one app that will act as a front-end app. Now, to apply the authentication in between these two app. I need to authenticate the request using token. Do you have any basic example to achieve that ?